# VBA run-time error "7" when naming xlXY ScatterLines chart

Tags: excel, charts, runtime-error, vba

I'm running a code that requires me to name a chart so I can refer back to it later. The code I use for this is:

```
Sheets("Summary").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
With ActiveChart
    .Name = "energy distribution chart"
End With
```

I've tried just naming the chart not using the with... as in:

```
ActiveChart.Name = "energy distribution chart"
```

Doesn't work also. Whenever the code runs at that line I get a "run-time error 7 - Out of memory". I've tried putting this code so that it starts to run in a new macro in a new module but it still always gets that error 7 - 3 lines into a new piece of code! I have no idea what's going on. Help?

Edit: Following to mehow's answer, how do I then re-select the chart?

I've tried:

```
With Worksheets("Summary").ChartObjects("energy distribution chart").Chart(1)
    .SeriesCollection(sheet_number - 1).XValues = Worksheets(sheet_number).Range(Sheets(sheet_number).Cells(1, 7), Sheets(sheet_number).Cells(i4, 7))
    .SeriesCollection(sheet_number - 1).Values = Worksheets(sheet_number).Range(Sheets(sheet_number).Cells(1, 8), Sheets(sheet_number).Cells(i4, 8))
End With
```

Which doesn't seem to work... .. hm. I've also tried getting rid of the (1) next to charts. Yep. No idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart it's an embed object. If you want to change of the object ( not chart itself ) then

```
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "chart name"
```

See [MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213725%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I'm just looking through the MSDN catalogue now, seriously confused! Hopefully I'll get my head around it, though. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: How do I reselect the chart so I can add a series later? I've tried: (Edit: Please see edit in question - too messy in comments!)