# VBA Referencing Named Range

Tags: vba, reference, named-ranges

I have defined a named using the following code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="BCLabel", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET(R46C3,1,0,COUNTA(R46C3:R69C3)-2)"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Names("BCLabel").Comment = ""
```

This code repeats for several worksheets, such that I have many named ranges titled BCLabel, although this refers to different ranges. For example

```
=OFFSET('January'!$C$46,1,0,COUNTA('January'!$C$46:$C$69)-2)
=OFFSET('February'!$C$46,1,0,COUNTA('February'!$C$46:$C$69)-2)
=OFFSET('March'!$C$46,1,0,COUNTA('March'!$C$46:$C$69)-2)
```

I would like to code the creation of a chart in each of these worksheets that references the correct named range. I have attempted the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.Name = "BCChart"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
    "==BCLabel"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = _
    "==BCLabel"
```

However this does not work: "==BCLabel" does not reference to the correct named range, nor does "==ActiveSheet.BCLabel". I would appreciate any assistance.

As an aside I have also encountered an error with the ActiveChart.Name = "BCChart" line.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [**`ActiveChart.Parent.Name`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973149/vba-run-time-error-7-when-naming-xlxy-scatterlines-chart/20973283#20973283)

Comment: why is there a double `==`?

Comment: @mehow I recorded a macro that set the ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values and this used a double ==, and I used this code and amended it accordingly to refer to the relevant named range.

Comment: from [what I can see](http://www.databison.com/create-chart-using-named-range-in-excel/) you need to qualify your named range providing the workbooks name, so `"==BCLabel"` should be `"=Book1.xlsm!BCLabel"` i think

Comment: @mehow I have attempted that with no luck. It appears that if I reference the worksheet name rather than the workbook name, then it works. However I have avoided referencing sheet names and have used ActiveSheet where possible - how could I use ActiveSheet in this context? ActiveSheet.YTD2013 or ActiveSheet!YTD2013 both do not work.

Comment: if the ActiveSheet works then you need to concatenate a string of two elements - the sheet name and the named range name. For example `...Values = "==" & Cstr(ActiveSheet) & "!BCLabel"`

Comment: @mehow I seem to get some form of syntax error with that code. Should it not be something along the lines of ..."= " & Cstr(ActiveSheet) & BCLabel"? This doesn't work either, I am just trying to clarify.

Comment: try `"=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!BCLabel"`

Comment: @mehow Still no luck. Doesn't the ! normally come after the worksheet name rather than before the named range? Doesn't the & symbol come between elements and not before? Are the " in the correct place?

Comment: please show me what works for you. the syntax

Comment: @mehow I am afraid I do not know what works, hence my question. In essence I need to find out how to refer to a named range on an active sheet, rather than a specific named sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code (this works for me):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("BCLabel")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range("BCLabel")
```

Btw it's better to avoid `Select` and `Active...` statements. So, I rewrote your code as follows:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim sh As Shape

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart

    With sh.Chart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws.Range("BCLabel")
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws.Range("BCLabel")
    End With

End Sub
```

About error in line `ActiveChart.Name = "BCChart"`, you can see in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197207%28v=office.15%29.aspx), that it's  read-only property for chart objects