# VBA Reference Named Range ActiveSheet

Tags: vba

How do I reference a named range on the ActiveSheet using VBA? I have several worksheets, each with a named range that uses the same title. None of the below work:

```
ActiveSheet.NamedRange
ActiveSheet!NamedRange
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("myNamedRange")
```

or just

```
Range("myNamedRange")
```

it's the same for `ActiveSheet`

If you need to get named range from another worksheet, use following code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("myNamedRange")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. To be more exact I am trying to use VBA to create a chart with the series values set to the named range. I have used the following code: ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.New Series, followed by ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values ="=ActiveSheet.Range("NamedRange")". However I get a syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this question is solved. For your second question see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135226/vba-referencing-named-range/21145700#21145700

Answer (score 1):

You may also reference it by bracket, example:

```
[my_table]
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.[my_table]
```

and you avoid using the quotation marks.