# Error in passing named range as argument in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem while passing ranges across two subprocedures. Can you suggest the possible error ?

I have defined two subprocedures in VBA. In the first subprocedure, I have a selection of cells (3X3 MATRIX), named under "ABC" which I'm copying to another selection of cells "PQR". This is working :)

I wanted to enable "all borders" when the values are copied on PQR from ABC. For this I recorded a macro.

**But, whenever I run this subprocedure, it is giving an error that object doesn't exist.**

I called the macro in the following manner :

```
All_border_test PQR
```

The code for subprocedure is as given below :

```
Sub All_borders_test(d As Range)
Range(d).Select

' Recorded Macro to enable all borders (its working) 
End Sub()
```

Comment: What about `Call All_border_test(..)`?

Comment: Just use d.Select instead of Range(d).Select. You already have a range object.

Comment: Hi Tom, I made the change as you said .. d.select. While calling I made this change .. Call All_borders_test(PQR) --- It is giving a compile error" Byref argument type mismatch"

Comment: It worked Houssam ! Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Take a look at:
 [What's the RIGHT way to reference named cells in Excel 2013 VBA? (I know I'm messing this up)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17228318/992406)  
and
 [VBA Reference Named Range ActiveSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21144644/992406) 

2- fix your  code to be like:

```
Sub All_borders_test(d As Range)
    d.Select ' old code was: Range(d).Select
End Sub 'no parenthesis here
```

3- you can call `All_borders_test` using one of the following calls:

```
Call All_borders_test([PQR])
Call All_borders_test(Range("PQR"))
Call All_borders_test(Sheet1.Range("PQR")) ' assuming that PQR range exists in Sheet1
```